# Make Bootstrap collapse button transition into position:absolute on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap sidebar that has the collapse toggle positioned half on and half off the sidebar like so.

[image]

When clicking the button I can collapse the sidebar successfully, however I'd like for the button itself to transition into a positon:absolute element and stay visible when the sidebar collapses.

I can do this by using some JQuery but it is pretty ugly and has no transition. I also don't know how to make it go back to position:relative once the user toggles the sidebar open again.

This is where I'm at currently...

```
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      $('#sidebarCollapse').css("position","absolute");
  });
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
  <nav id="sidebar" class="active">
    <div class="custom-menu">
      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4">
      <h1><a href="index.html" class="logo">Flightology</a></h1>
      <ul class="list-unstyled components my-5">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home mr-3"></span> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-user mr-3"></span> About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-briefcase mr-3"></span> one</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-sticky-note mr-3"></span> two</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-paper-plane mr-3"></span> three</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
  <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
    <h2 class="mb-4">Sidebar #03</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: gray;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -o-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #fff!important;
}


.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 270px;
  max-width: 270px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #3C4F76;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -270px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
      margin-left: -270px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
}

#sidebar .custom-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#sidebar .custom-menu .btn.btn-primary {
  background: #AB9F9D;
  border-color: #AB9F9D;
}

#sidebar .custom-menu .btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #3C4F76;
}



#sidebar h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#sidebar h1 .logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.p-4 {
  padding: 1.5rem !important;
}

.p-md-5 {
  padding: 3rem !important;
}
```

UPDATE

I have added a class

```
.btn-toggled {
  position: absolute;
}
```

And I can toggle this with the JQuery, however the transition is pretty ugly still. Is there a way to transition between relative and absolute positioning?

```
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      $('#sidebarCollapse').toggleClass('btn-toggled');
  });
```

Comment: Please give more code - html, css..

Comment: Where do you want the button to be placed, when the menu is closed? Does it have to always stay half on and half off the sidebar?